# .Htaccess to exclude path and run WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, web-applications

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/.*$` it doesn't work

I have no clue what app is running on the current site, I can't install wordpress on example.com/blog because it returned me 404 page. How do I exclude example.com/blog to avoid running the existing webapp but to install wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like CakePHP's `.htaccess`.

Replace the current `.htaccess` code with the given one.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule (blog/.*) $1 [L] 
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Before making any changes don't forget to take a backup of your current `.htaccess` file.